# Is there any way to show a specific Service Category in Amelia Booking Plugin Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am creating a booking website, I am showing some products to user on a page which he wants to appoint for. On clicking one product, the user is redirected to the booking page of Amelia plugin. The problem is that there are many products and I don't want to show all the service Categories of Amelia on a single page, and also don't want to create a separate booking page for every product.

Is there any Solution for this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

**"JUST SOLVED IT"**

So I was looking for a solution that targets all the services in a single page, but only show the service that user clicks on the previous page.

The solution I came through was some custom HTML code (Paste this code on the page you are trying to show services):

```
<div id="show"> [ameliacatalog category=7] </div>
    // Some more services like this
    <style>
        #show{
            display:none;
        }
    // Hide services by their IDs
    </style>
    
    <script>
        var id = window.location.hash;
        id = id.substring(1);
        myFunction(id);
    
        function myFunction(id){
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
        }
    </script>
```

And Now you can redirect links on your products or images like this

https://example.com/page#show

Thank me later ;)